# Navigate to InApp screen from webview URL

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I have a flutter app which has a web-view and browsing a specific URL. The web-view has form, when it is filled and submitted, the web-view redirects the user to the result URL according to his form fillings.

For example: The web-view browses `www.example.com/form`, when the user filled out the form and submit it, the application redirecting the user according to the filling to the resulting URL for example to `www.example2.com`.

This result URL `www.example2.com` is something which I have control on it to change it to something other value which needed.

What I want is, after the user filled out the form and submitted, how I can navigate the user from web-view to an InApp screen/widget of my flutter application? That in-app screen should be opened by web-view's redirection parameter.

For example, I can tell the web-view that once the form filled, navigate the user to `OpenWidget`.

I can say also: Is it possible to navigate to another widget from web-view's URL.